# Reference for elliptic regularity for $-\triangle \phi + u \cdot \nabla\phi=f$ under minimal assumptions

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations

I have a distributional solution to $-\triangle \phi + u \cdot \nabla \phi= f$ in $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\phi=0$ on $\partial U$.

I have that $U$ is open, bounded, connected, $f:\overline{U}\to \mathbb{R}^+$ is continuous, and  $u:U \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is Lipschitz.

I would like to conclude that $\phi \in C^2(U)$ by elliptic regularity. Does anyone have a reference which covers the case I am working in? Extra assumptions on $U$ (like $C^1$ boundary, etc.) or on $u$ would be okay, but I cannot make any extra assumptions on $f$.

Edit: I would like to not assume anything extra on $u$ beyond Lipschitz or possibly $C^1$.

Comment: Even with $u\equiv 0$ this is not true: the continuity of Laplacian does not imply the function is $C^2$. (Example: $\phi(x,y)=xy\sqrt{|\log(x^2+y^2)|}$.) A reasonable compromise is to assume $f$ is Hölder (locally) continuous. By the way this is an interior regularity issue, so the shape of domain is irrelevant.

Comment: Could I get $\phi \in C^1$?

Comment: I guess so; the optimal result should be $C^{1,\alpha}$ for every $\alpha\in (0,1)$. I'll look for a reference.

Comment: @cheapeffectivedietpills $C^{1,\alpha}$ would be perfect. I ask because in my case $f = \exp(\phi)$, so if I knew $\phi \in C^{1,\alpha}$ then I could bootstrap. Reference would be very helpful, I'm searching too.

Comment: I think Theorem 8.34 in the Gilbarg-Trudinger book does the job. The assumption on $f$ there is $L^\infty$.

Comment: 8.34? The highest numbered theorem in chapter 8 in my version is 8.30

Comment: I have the 1998 edition, reprinted by Springer in the *Classics in Mathematics* series. Here is [Theorem 8.34](http://i.stack.imgur.com/dblV8.png); [condition (8.85)](http://i.stack.imgur.com/yktN2.png); the other conditions (8.5), (8.6) are ellipticity and boundedness of coefficients. Maybe they have different numbers in your edition.